# Ocultar la mitad del texto y mostrar puntos suspensivos al final, si un párrafo es muy extenso

Tags: javascript, html, css

Me gustaría saber si se puede reducir la longitud de un párrafo demasiado largo a la mitad y que al darle clic encima del párrafo me despliegue el resto del texto.
Me acaban de dar esta opción con DETAILS y SUMMARY que es lo más cercan a lo que quiero lograr, salvo que necesito que el párrafo termine en puntos suspensivos y luego al darle clic al texto se vea la continuación sin cortar el texto en dos... Aparte que el recuadro que se ve en el ejemplo sea invisible.

```
<html> 
</style>
<body>
    <details>
        <summary style="display: block;">
            Hamas gano combinando una fuerte resistencia contra la ocupacion militar con la
            creacion de organizaciones sociales de base y de servicio a los pobres, una plataforma
            y una practica que probablemente haria ganar votos en cualquier lugar. La victoria
            electoral de Hamas es ominosa pero comprensible, a la luz de los acontecimientos.
            Es enteramente justo describir a Hamas como fundamentalista, extremista y violentista,
            y como una seria amenaza a la paz y a un acuerdo politicamente justo. Sin embargo,
            es útil recordar que en aspectos importantes, Hamas no es tan extremista como otros.
            Por ejemplo, declara que estaría de acuerdo con una tregua con Israel sobre la base
            de la frontera reconocida a nivel internacional antes de la guerra arabe-israeli de
            junio de l967 La posición de Washington hacia las elecciones en Palestina ha sido... 
        </summary>
    
        <p>
            coherente. Las elecciones fueron postergadas hasta la muerte de Yasser Arafat,
            que fue recibida como una oportunidad para la realización de la "visión" de Bush
            sobre un eventual Estado palestino democrativo, que es una palido y vago reflejo
            del consenso internacional sobre una acuerdo de dos entidades estatales en la zona,
            que Estados Unidos viene bloqueando desde hace 30 años,El compromiso formal de Hamas
            de "destruir Israel" lo pone a la par con Estados Unidos e Israel, que prometieron
            por mucho tiempo que no habria ningun "Estado palestino adicional" (aparte de Jordania"
            , hasta que ambas naciones aflojaron parcialmente su posicion, para aceptar un mini 
            Estado constituido por los fragmentos que queden despues que Israel se apropie de todas
            las partes de Palestina que desea....
        </p>
    </details>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar solamente JavaScript y CSS, usando la propiedad [`text-overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow).

Haremos que al presionar el párrafo se elimine o se añada la clase de CSS que tendrá ese texto. Usando [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) para escuchar el evento de `click` y también usaremos [`classList.toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), así, se eliminará la clase si ya existe en el elemento, o se añadirá si no existe.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".-b-expander").forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener("click", () => {
    el.classList.toggle("-b-text-undexpanded");
  });
});
```

```css
.-b-text-undexpanded {
  display: -webkit-box;
  height: 105.2px;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 5; /* Número de líneas */
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  line-height: 1.3;
}

.-b-expander {
  cursor: pointer;1
  line-height: 1.3;
}
```

```html
<p class="-b-expander -b-text-undexpanded"> Hamas gano combinando una fuerte resistencia contra la ocupacion militar con la creacion de organizaciones sociales de base y de servicio a los pobres, una plataforma y una practica que probablemente haria ganar votos en cualquier lugar. La victoria electoral de Hamas es ominosa pero comprensible, a la luz de los acontecimientos. Es enteramente justo describir a Hamas como fundamentalista, extremista y violentista, y como una seria amenaza a la paz y a un acuerdo politicamente justo. Sin embargo, es útil recordar que en aspectos importantes, Hamas no es tan extremista como otros. Por ejemplo, declara que estaría de acuerdo con una tregua con Israel sobre la base de la frontera reconocida a nivel internacional antes de la guerra arabe-israeli de junio de l967 La posición de Washington hacia las elecciones en Palestina ha sido coherente. Las elecciones fueron postergadas hasta la muerte de Yasser Arafat, que fue recibida como una oportunidad para la realización de la "visión" de Bush sobre un eventual Estado palestino democrativo, que es una palido y vago reflejo del consenso internacional sobre una acuerdo de dos entidades estatales en la zona, que Estados Unidos viene bloqueando desde hace 30 años,El compromiso formal de Hamas de "destruir Israel" lo pone a la par con Estados Unidos e Israel, que prometieron por mucho tiempo que no habria ningun "Estado palestino adicional" (aparte de Jordania" , hasta que ambas naciones aflojaron parcialmente su posicion, para aceptar un mini Estado constituido por los fragmentos que queden despues que Israel se apropie de todas las partes de Palestina que desea </p>
```

Uso [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) para obtener los elementos que tengan la clase `-b-expander` (la puedes modificar), que será un `<p>` donde almacenaremos el texto, simplemente le añadiremos el evento y activaremos o desactivaremos la clase según el contexto.

Comment: Hola @RodrigoRamirez Gracias por tu respuesta en el caso de no hacerlo con boton Expandir si no que haga la misma funcion pero al darle clic al parrafo como seria?

Comment: @Alayna Añadiendo el evento directamente al texto, puedes revisar el ejemplo funcionando en mi respuesta actualizada.

Comment: Increible! te amo! era lo que buscaba muchas gracias!! sin embargo me surge una inquietud extra...es posible limitar la longitud de lo que se muestra antes de darle clic? por ejemplo que muestre solo 5 lineas de texto antes de darle clic y luego que si muestre el resto?

Comment: @Alayna Usando CSS puedes lograr hacerlo, revisa nuevamente mi respuesta, espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Me recontra sirvió eres el mejor! gracias ojala tener un maestro como tu para aprender mas :c